# Importing module command line in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have set of unit test case and they are invoking a set of PowerShell commands. everything works fine on local machine but once pushed in to Azure pipelines, I get error as "New-CosmosDbContext is not recognized. Please check the spelling". It seems the Import command is not working when pushed to azure devops pipeline. Any idea as how we can fix this?

The lines what I am using is :

```
Import-Module "$env:ProgramFiles\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\PSModules\Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Emulator"
    Start-CosmosDbEmulator    
    Get-CosmosDbEmulatorStatus
$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Emulator
```

Comment: @mklement0 if you can check this https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB
 it seems they are and I am able to run it locally. if I remove Import Module, it fails in very first command Start-CosmosDbEmulator

Answer (score 0):

As your [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68179535/45375) implies, you have since realized that *two different modules* are involved, and that you *also* need to import the third-party `CosmosDB` module in order to use its `New-CosmosDbContext` command:

- [`Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Emulator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/emulator-command-line-parameters) is the *official* Azure CosmosDB module.
- [`CosmosDB`](https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB) is a *third-party* module.

  - Therefore, you need to first *install* the module (from the [Powershell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CosmosDB/)) - e.g., `Install-Module CosmosDB -Scope CurrentUser` - and then import it - `ImportModule CosmosDB` - before you can call `New-CosmosDbContext`