# Unable to install NuGet provider by invoking powershell in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, nuget

I am calling powershell cmdlet from my below C# method and it fails at line Install-Module Name CosmosDb with the below error

> "Exception calling "ShouldContinue" with "2" argument(s): "A command
> that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command
> type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to
> request confirmation with the following message: PowerShellGet
> requires NuGet provider version '2.8.5.201' or newer to interact with
> NuGet-based repositories. The NuGet provider must be available in
> 'C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies' or
> 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies'.
> You can also install the NuGet provider by running
> 'Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201
> -Force'. Do you want PowerShellGet to install and import the NuGet provider now?"

C# Code:

```
{            
            InitialSessionState initialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
            initialSessionState.ExecutionPolicy = ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;
            using Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace( initialSessionState );
            string path = Path.Combine( CosmosDataFixture.Root , @"TestData\GetrRecording.ps1" );
            runspace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript( path );
            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
            runspace.Close();
}
```

Powershell cmdlets in my ps1 script file

```
ECHO 'Y'|Import-Module "$env:ProgramFiles\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\PSModules\Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Emulator"
Install-Module PowershellGet -Force -Scope CurrentUser
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.208 -Force 
Install-Module -Name CosmosDB -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

I needed 1st and last line here but error prompt me to add the two in middl

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68179928/45375), **you cannot use PowerShell commands that request *interactive* input from the user when you use the PowerShell SDK**, so your only option is to *avoid* such interactive prompts, which, depending on the specific command, requires `-Force` or `-Confirm:$false` (though note that *neither* parameter may be supported).

- [`Install-PackageProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/packagemanagement/install-packageprovider) supports `-Confirm`, so you should try `-Confirm:$false` (possibly in combination with `-Force`) to see if that programmatically confirms the normally interactive prompt.
- [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) supports `-Force`, but it doesn't *itself* ever prompt the user; instead `-Force` signals the intent to force-reload an already-imported module.

  - What *can* happen, however (as suggested by your feedback) is that module being imported tries to create an *elevated* (run-as-admin) process, which invariably makes **the *system* put up a [UAC (User Account Control)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) prompt** ("Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?") to confirm the intent to perform this security-sensitive operation.

    - By design, this UAC prompt can *not* be answered *programmatically*, for security reasons.
  - **Your only option is to run your program *itself* with elevation**, such as from a PowerShell console that was started by right-clicking on the PowerShell icon and selecting `Run as Administrator`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

Note:

- The following makes a *general* point about programmatically responding to *PowerShell* prompts. As stated above, it isn't actually `Import-Module` itself that puts up prompts, but in your case it is the specific module being imported; that prompt (`"Do you want this app to make changes to your computer?"`) is a UAC prompt put up by the *system* and can by design *not* be answered programmatically.

```
ECHO 'Y' | Import-Module ...
```

invariably *fails*, because **you fundamentally cannot answer PowerShell's interactive prompts using (PowerShell) *pipeline* input**.

- The only way to programmatically respond to interactive *PowerShell* prompts is if the PowerShell *CLI* is called and the responses are provided via *stdin* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66550241/45375).

Presumably you didn't see the failure (`Import-Module: The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.`), because it isn't directly reported by the `.Invoke()` return value (which only comprises *success* output); to check for *errors* (the error stream), use [`pipeline.Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline.Error)

Comment: I tried to follow the other answer in your post but couldnt figure out how can i use stdin in my code? can you show that with my code?

Comment: If we're talking about the UAC prompt ("Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?"), there is no solution. It is a prompt shown by the _system_, not PowerShell, and it is designed _not_ to allow responding to _programmatically_. Hypothetically, you can disable UAC altogether, but that is strongly discouraged for security reasons.